# Adding values to JTable as dynamicly

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, dynamic, jtable

I have a textbox which sent something to database and jtable list the values from database. But when i add something to database. Jtable dont show it in same time. when i close the program and debug again, it shows that time. I want Jtabel to show textbox value when i click the save button. How can i create a dynamic jtable?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class Topic extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    JFrame frmTopic;
    JPanel pnl, pnl_generaltopic;
    static JTextField txt_topic;
    JLabel lbl_topicNme, lbl_topicpage;
    JButton btn_close, btn_update, btn_save;
    public static Connection con = null;
    public static ResultSet rs = null;
    public static Statement st = null;
    static Vector<Vector<String>> data = new Vector<Vector<String>>();
    private JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private static JTable table;

    public Topic() {
        pnl_generaltopic = new JPanel();
        pnl_generaltopic.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        pnl_generaltopic.setLayout(null);

        frmTopic = new JFrame("Topic");
        frmTopic.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {

                con = Dbconnect.conect();
            }
        });
        frmTopic.setTitle("E-TEST");
        frmTopic.setBounds(100, 100, 500, 500);
        frmTopic.setVisible(true);
        frmTopic.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frmTopic.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        frmTopic.getContentPane().add(pnl_generaltopic);

        topicPanel();
        topicTable();
    }

    public void topicPanel() {

        JPanel panel_addingNewTopic = new JPanel();
        panel_addingNewTopic.setBounds(10, 0, 464, 203);
        pnl_generaltopic.add(panel_addingNewTopic);
        panel_addingNewTopic.setLayout(null);
        btn_save = new JButton("Save");
        btn_save.setBounds(65, 166, 67, 23);
        panel_addingNewTopic.add(btn_save);
        btn_update = new JButton("Update");
        btn_update.setBounds(142, 162, 90, 30);
        panel_addingNewTopic.add(btn_update);
        btn_close = new JButton("Close");
        btn_close.setBounds(240, 162, 90, 30);
        panel_addingNewTopic.add(btn_close);
        txt_topic = new JTextField();
        txt_topic.setBounds(65, 59, 270, 71);
        panel_addingNewTopic.add(txt_topic);


        lbl_topicNme = new JLabel("Topic Name");
        lbl_topicNme.setBounds(10, 65, 150, 59);
        panel_addingNewTopic.add(lbl_topicNme);
        lbl_topicpage = new JLabel("Topic Page");
        lbl_topicpage.setBounds(10, 11, 300, 20);
        panel_addingNewTopic.add(lbl_topicpage);
        lbl_topicpage.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 15));


        btn_close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                            frmTopic.dispose();
                                        }
                                    }
        );

        btn_save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                           try {

                                               st = con.createStatement();
                                               String sorgu = "insert into topic " + "(topicname)"
                                                       + "VALUES ('" + txt_topic.getText() + "')";
                                               st.executeUpdate(sorgu);
                                               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Topic.this, "Topic was added");
                                           } catch (Exception s) {
                                               System.out.print(s.getMessage());
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }
        );
    }


    public void topicTable() {

        scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 226, 464, 190);
        pnl_generaltopic.add(scrollPane);

        Vector<String> headers = new Vector<String>();
        headers.add("Topic Name");


        getData();

        //this is the model which contain actual body of JTable
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, headers);
        table = new JTable(model);
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(table);
        table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
        //table=new JTable(model);
        //table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);

        header_size();

        //JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);

        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

        pack();
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }


    /**
     * Setting the particular Column Size in JTable
     */
    public static void header_size() {
        TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        column.setPreferredWidth(100);

        column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
        column.setPreferredWidth(350);
    }


    /**
     * Fetching Data From MySql Database
     * and storing in a Vector of a Vector
     * to Display in JTable
     */
    private static void getData() {
        // Enter Your MySQL Database Table name in below Select Query.
        String str = "select * from topics";
        Connection con;
        ResultSet rs;
        Statement st;

        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + "localhost:3306/database", "root", "1234");
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery(str);

            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector<String> d = new Vector<String>();

                d.add(rs.getString("topicname"));

                d.add("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                data.add(d);
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Topic topic = new Topic();
        topic.setVisible(false);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `addRow(...)` method of the `DefaultTableModel` to dynamically add a row of data in the model.

So if the update to your database is successful, then you would invoke the addRow() method.

Also, you should use a PreparedStatement when using SQL. It will make creating the SQL easier since you don't need to worry about the delimiters. Simple example to give you an idea:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO Page (Name, Title) VALUES (?, ?)";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString( 1, "Name1" );
stmt.setString( 2, textField.getText() );
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: You might want to call Update() on the table after adding the row just to make sure it knows to redraw.  (I forget whether the DefaultTableModel does this or not.)

Comment: @user430788, no there is no need to call Update() after adding the row. It is the responsibility of the TableModel to notify the JTable when the data changes so the table can repaint itself. In fact you should never call update() on any Swing component.

Comment: i tried addRow but no solution. can you give some code that works?

Comment: @user3536626, Its one line of code to use the addRow() method. You  can always search the forum or the web for examples that use that method. Or, is you still need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that shows what you tried. Of course the SSCCE will not include your database code since we do not have access to your database.